# Why was my question and account deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions

It's this question: [“He 'is to be' here by six o'clock.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/514110/191178) (deleted)

I made an account some days ago trying to find out the answer to a question about what the name of the verb conjugation be + infinitive (is to be, are to run, was to call) is called and have been checking back for an answer and answering questions here and there and had gotten about 50 points and now I check today and my question and my account don't exist anymore and when I try and ask why  on some "meta" site it says I can't because I don't have enough points and because that question doesn't exist but it made this account when I tried so I'm asking here.

Why was my question and account deleted?

Comment: This is a question for Meta, but since you don't have enough rep. Try asking on the help at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I know because that's where it sent me but when I got there it says I can't put a question there because I don't have enough points.  I said all this above.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: Thank you for the link.

Comment: They should be able to give you a reason you'd have been deleted.

Comment: Your question appears to have been deleted because it had enough close votes. It needed to be expanded upon to be clearer what you needed explained. Your account is a bigger mystery.

Answer (score 11):

It is our policy that when a user account is suspended, any accounts that are created to circumvent that suspension are deleted without notice.

If you have further questions or if you want to appeal the decision, you can contact  SE staff: english.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: I read the last part of OP's question carefully, and it doesn't appear to me that this user purposely intended to create a new account.  I would urge the moderators to reach out to this user by email to see if something can be clarified and if there's a snafu, that it be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I fear there is nothing that can be done. I hope I'm mistaken, but once an account has been deleted that's it. If a moderator deleted an account by mistake then there is a glimmer of hope…

> [No, this is not possible. Once a profile is deleted, it is gone forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283926/223820).
>
> We can restore past content to a new profile, but we only do so for users who were deleted erroneously, usually due to a moderator making a mistake (I've done it a couple of times myself). If you requested the deletion in any way, then the content will remain anonymous forever.
>
> @animusan♦ Aug 27 '16

Answer (score -7):

From the information I've garnered so far on the Meta Page, there is no required feedback nor defined structure in which a moderator can act. There are processes that are put into place to review decisions, but from what I've seen so far it's essentially a pointless endeavour.

A post such as this is the best you can hope for, but if you hope to find out exactly why this action has been taken you just have to hope the moderators/high rep users feel inclined to tell you. There is no burden on their part to actually quantify their actions on users to the users themselves.